# playback of audio server response blocked by iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, audio, text-to-speech

I am working on a speech to speech chatbot (you talk to it, it talks back). Everything is working fine on desktop, but the server response does not play back on iOS if it is part of the audio submission function (see below):

```
// record audio and submit it
function startRecording() {

    // set mediaRecorder options (depending on browser support)
    if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm; codecs=opus')) { //opus as preferred codec
        var options = {mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus', audioBitsPerSecond: 64000};
    } else  if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm')) {
        var options = {mimeType: 'audio/webm', audioBitsPerSecond: 64000};
    } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/mp4')) { //mp4 for IOS
        var options = {mimeType: 'audio/mp4', audioBitsPerSecond: 64000};
    } else {
        console.error("no suitable mimetype found for this device");
    }

    // create recorder using audio stream and set options
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options); //recorder created after used approved mic access

    // error handling
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
      console.error("Error during audio recording:", event.error);
      alert("Audio recording error: Please try again.");
    });

    // listen to available data from media recorder
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
        // check for data in recorded chunk
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
            // push chunks to array
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        }
    });

    // listen for stop event (recording button let go)
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        // create blob from recordedChunks array
        const audioBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: options.mimeType});
        // reset the recorded chunks array
        recordedChunks = [];

        // create form data and append audio to it
        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("recording", audioBlob);

        // create XMLHttpRequest object to send the data
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // set request method and URL
        xhr.open("POST", "/audio", true);

        // event listener for response
        xhr.onload = function () {
          console.log("conversation response received");
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // parse response
            let receivedData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            // extract text and display it
            let receivedText = receivedData.text;
            responseText.textContent = receivedText;

            // extract audio link and play it
            let receivedAudioDataLink = receivedData.audio;
            audioResponse = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + receivedAudioDataLink);

            // enable replay and download buttons if first response
            if (conversationStarted == false) {
              replayButton.disabled = false;
              conversationStarted = true;
            }

            // play audio response
            audioResponse.play();
          } else {
            console.error("An error occurred during the transaction: ", xhr.status);
          }
        };
        // send FormData object
        xhr.send(fd);
        console.log("audio recording sent");
    });
  // start of recording
  mediaRecorder.start();
  console.log("audio recording started");
}

function stopRecording() {
  if (mediaRecorder) {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    console.log("audio recording stopped");
  }
}

recordButton.addEventListener("mousedown", startRecording);
recordButton.addEventListener("mouseup", stopRecording);
```

The only way I can get the audio to play back is via a separate button such as this:

```
replayButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  audioResponse.play();
})
```

I would like to avoid this explicit push of a button as I want to play the audio response as soon as it is received (to make the system faster and more user friendly). I suspect that the audio playback is not working due to iOS blocking autoplay - I am confused by this though, as the audio submission only happens if the user engages with the page and submits audio so he would want to listen to the response as well. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you read something like this warning in console? "The AudioContext was not allowed to start [...]"

Comment: I did not! I was able to solve my problem through webkit though (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem - it was indeed an issue with the autoplay restrictions. This can be solved via introducing an audio context at the beginning of the recording function

```
audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

after receiving the server response this audio context can be used to play the audio by

```
function playAudio() {
  // stop old audio if playing
  if (sourceNode) {
    sourceNode.stop(0);
    sourceNode.disconnect();
  }

  // create new source node for playing audio
  sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();

  // assign decoded audio buffer to source node
  sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;

  // connect to established audio context and play
  sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
  sourceNode.start(0);
}
```